# Getting error: "saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../package.json'

Tags: node.js, npm-install, package.json

I am attempting to install newsapi via the command: `npm install newsapi --save`.
That installs two dependent packages (core-js and node-fetch) as well as newsapi itself. I run the command in my project folder. I have no issues with core-js and node-fetch, but I get the following warnings regarding newsapi.

```sh
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Users/user_name/project/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Users/user_name/project/package.json'
npm WARN project No description
npm WARN project No repository field.
npm WARN project No README data
npm WARN project No license field.
```

After the installation, `package-lock.json` is created in my project folder and `Users/user_name/project/node-modules/newsapi/package.json` does exist. I don't know why the installation asks me to open `Users/user_name/project/package.json`. Why would it be in my project folder and not in the module's folder?

I tried solutions I read in other threads including deleting `package-lock.json` and retrying the installation and using `npm init`. Neither of those methods worked.

I also tried copying and pasting `package.json` to the project folder (because the warnings prompt me to open `Users/user_name/project/package.json`) but that did not solve my problems either.

How can I successfully install the module?

Comment: It could be the permission issue, can you please check if the user that you are running the command with has permission to open and write `package.json`?

Comment: I have full control (including read and write access) according to the file's security property.